# I have a soap service deployed on wso2 apim 4.0.0. While working with the api I randomly get Error on line 1: Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have a soap service deployed on wso2 apim 4.0.0. While working with the api I randomly (rarely) get an error - "Content is not allowed in prolog". Is there any component of the configuration to be tuned to overcome this issue? Another version of the cause of this error, I found out in [the article](https://mkyong.com/java/sax-error-content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog/), this might be caused by a consumer that is not able to properly invoke the api. Any hint to find out the root of the problem is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Enable wire logs[1] and check whether the backend is sending a corrupted response while you are reproducing the issue.
A corrupted response means such as a chunked response but, the Content-Length header is available in the response.
You can compare the wire logs for both the happy path and the issue scenario.

[1] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/integrate/develop/using-wire-logs/